# Custom analyzer or multi language support for same field

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am trying to see possible solutions to deal with multi-language search functionality using Azure Cognitive Search. For the index below, the Name field has various language related options for Analyzer, but it supports only one language per field.

[image]

Is there a way to have multi-language support in an index?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-language-support) should help. In summary, you'll need multiple fields, one for each language. The article discusses options for how to structure queries over those fields.

Comment: My ask is to avoid multiple fields as one field may get various language words, ex: customer name, it sounds same but words different from language to language, I can't maintain multiple fields for this reason.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/

how about this one ? a good choice for my requirement.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create a custom analyzer that can do a good job of analyzing terms for all the supported languages.

The multi-field approach can work even if you don't know the language of the incoming data. Just copy the data to each of the language-specific fields, and include them all in each query (using "or" or searchMode=any).